# How to solve "AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have searched several answers to this question, however, they do not solve my problem.

My current code is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

startDate = '2018-02-01'
endDate = '2018-03-01'

startDate = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
endDate = datetime.strptime(endDate, '%Y-%m-%d')

for i in range(2,10):
   returns.loc[startDate+datetime.timedelta(days=10*i):endDate+(10*i)+datetime.timedelta(days=10*i)]
```

which gives:
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timedelta'

Comment: Are you using `from datetime import datetime`? If so, I think you want `from datetime import datetime, timedelta` and then just call `timedelta(...)` in your code.

Comment: you should do `import datetime` and then `datetime.timedelta` and NOT `from datetime import datetime
`

Comment: Yes, it wasn't showing in the original post for some reason

Comment: as per your code, you only need to do `timedelta(days=10*i)` and NOT `datetime.timedelta(days=10*i)`

Comment: Yes, this works

Comment: I won't chime in on the solution as the comments above are right, but it would make it easier for people to answer your question if you made your code reproducible, i.e. created a toy dataframe `returns`, which exhibited the salient characteristics of the dataframe you're trying to work with.